How do I go about grouping visits that fall within a certain timeframe? by emp_id, time_in, time_out, via highest duration



cv_id
Emp_Id
revin
revout
Duration




14
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120


25
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120


12
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120


20
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120


25
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120


26
411
2022-07-06 09:15:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
105


27
411
2022-07-06 09:25:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
95


28
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 10:00:00
60


29
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 10:00:00
60


32
411
2022-07-06 10:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
60


31
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60


30
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60


35
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60


36
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60


39
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 13:31:00
31




View on DB Fiddle
 If you look at timeframe from 9am to 11am you can see that there 
 was a group gathering, then 13:00 to 14:00 has its own group 
 gathering.
 This what I want as the outcome:
 




cv_id
Emp_Id
revin
revout
Duration
Rank




14
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120
1


25
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120
2


12
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120
3


20
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
120
4


26
411
2022-07-06 09:15:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
105
5


27
411
2022-07-06 09:25:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
95
6


28
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 10:00:00
60
7


29
411
2022-07-06 09:00:00
2022-07-06 10:00:00
60
8


32
411
2022-07-06 10:00:00
2022-07-06 11:00:00
60
9


31
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60
1


30
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60
2


35
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60
3


36
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 14:00:00
60
4


39
411
2022-07-06 13:00:00
2022-07-06 13:31:00
31
5




View on DB Fiddle

What is your desired output based on your example? Please update the question.

@Isolated Made changes to show desired output.

Try
rank () over (partition by emp_id  order by duration desc, visit_id asc) rank     


I want group by emp_id and timein.

Not quite like this. I've made some changes to be more clear.

Perhaps, you want some like this
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by emp_id order by duration desc, visit_id) rn
from visits

Result



visit_id
emp_id
time_in
timeout
duration
rn




15
2
2012-03-14 09:30:00.000
2012-03-14 10:30:00.000
60
1


16
2
2012-03-14 10:00:00.000
2012-03-14 11:00:00.000
60
2


18
2
2012-03-14 10:00:00.000
2012-03-14 11:00:00.000
60
3


25
2
2012-03-14 10:00:00.000
2012-03-14 11:00:00.000
60
4


33
5
2012-05-16 13:30:00.000
2012-05-16 15:30:00.000
120
1


30
5
2012-05-16 13:00:00.000
2012-05-16 14:30:00.000
90
2



Or
select *
from(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by emp_id order by duration desc, visit_id) rn
  from visits
  )t
where rn=1

result is



visit_id
emp_id
time_in
timeout
duration
rn




15
2
2012-03-14 09:30:00.000
2012-03-14 10:30:00.000
60
1


33
5
2012-05-16 13:30:00.000
2012-05-16 15:30:00.000
120
1



Demo

I want group by emp_id and timein.
